# Setting up ssh on mac OSx

Tags: macos, git, ssh

I am trying to set up a git server on my local mac machine.
I followed steps mentioned in the [link](http://blog.smitec.net/posts/setting-up-a-git-server-on-osx/).

But somehow even though I am able to ping the machine, when I try to connect to the machine using ssh git@ip_address.com, it gives error- "Permission denied (public key)"

Not able to find an answer for this error.
If someone faced the issue and has a solution, please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

My command line data:

```
Kaustubhs-Pro:~ kaustubh$ ssh git@192.168.43.115 -v
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.43.115 [192.168.43.115] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/kaustubh/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/kaustubh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kaustubh/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/kaustubh/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 
b2:59:8a:cc:f8:1a:76:8f:2a:6f:f5:a1:2b:f1:ff:10
debug1: Host '192.168.43.115' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/kaustubh/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/kaustubh/.ssh/my_git_key
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/kaustubh/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/kaustubh/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no valid key in your your actual user **kaustubh** that can be used for the SSH auth. So add your public key to the `authorized_keys` of your GIT user.

So you can use

```
ssh-copy-id git@192.168.43.115
```

To add your actual public key to the git authorized keys. You have to login with username and password for the first time.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I didn't add the pub key on the server.
So I copied, my keygen.pub on the server and then copied the content into authorized_keys.
This solved the issue. 
Thanks.